# Redirection if no parameters in the URL in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I use the Lumen framework for some time and I find myself confronted with a recurrent problem.

In my example, the page **`/index/validation/`** requires a parameter, here represented by **`{key}`**. However, call **`/index/validation/`** without parameter, I don't see how to don't have the page not found exception.

So, I created a function to redirect to the home page

**routes.php**

```
$app->get('/index/validation', 'App\Http\Controllers\IndexController@redirectIndex');
$app->get('/index/validation/{key}', 'App\Http\Controllers\IndexController@validation');
```

**IndexController**

```
public function redirectIndex() {
    return redirect('index');
}
```

What am I doing here works fine, however, I am not sure whether to apply the right method, or maybe there is another way to achieve my goal ?

Comment: If you don't see a page not found, what do you see then?

Comment: If I don't add route "redirectIndex", I have a page not found

Comment: Ah I see. Do you want to redirect on all page not found errors or just this one?

Comment: I haven't found yet how to redirect all, but this should be better for all. I don't understand how to redirect the not found pages to a view...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All uncaught exceptions are handled within `App\Exceptions\Handler`. To redirect on all not found exceptions change the `render()` method to this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException){
        return redirect('index');
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

You also have to import the class with:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I suppose that I have several separate folders where everyone owns his index, how to proceed?

Comment: Maybe something like `redirect($request->segment(1))` works for you